# How Do I Run A Continuous Loop In ASPNET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application running a large number of RESTful calls on a server and I need to add in the ability to ping the local devices to ensure they are alive.  That "ping" is actually a RESTful call in and of itself with a boolean response.

While I could simply write a Windows Service to do this work, I am hoping that there is some way to run this process continuously within the context of my application.  I tried running async Tasks every way I could think of but I am clearly doing something wrong.

I found AsyncContext (https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) and have used it to run other things but I am clearly not using it correctly as the loop hangs the entire application.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1 ?

Comment: Thank you for this reference!  Can you please provide as an Answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: This call fails:  using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())

Comment: Nevermind - I forgot to add using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;